# Heteroscedasticity-consistent standard error is not the same as OLS standard error

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

**Problem**
I perform the following regression
$$ y_i = a + b x_i +\epsilon, \quad \quad i = 1, ..., 21$$
I managed to estimate $\hat a = −0.59$ and $\hat b = 0.069$ with standard error $s.e.(\hat b) = 0.007$ and $R^2 = 0.84$.
I also, estimate White heteroscedasticity-consistent standard error of $b$ and get that
$s.e.(\hat b)_{W} = 0.01$.
What does it imply?

**My ideas**
I think that we have heteroscedasticity in our data because $s.e.(\hat b)_{W}$ standard error considering heteroscedasticity is not the same as $ s.e.(\hat b)$ standard error that doesn't consider heteroscedasticity.
My other idea is that we can use some test to check this.

Comment: Your notation suggests the point estimates are different between OLS and White. However, the point estimates are the same but the standard errors differ. Therefore, I would put the subscript to $\text{s.e.}$, not to $\hat{b}$.

Comment: You are right. I made an edit.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I would have indexed $\text{s.e.}$, not $(\hat{b})$, but it is of course your choice.